# Blank Map with Zoom buttons (Google Maps API V2)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

NB - I've been through this site with a fine toothed comb and can't find an answer that helps me. Though, this seems to be a common problem for whatever reason.

I'm a proper noob at Java, and I'm currently teaching myself. I'm working towards GeoFencing, but obviously need to learn about including Maps in my app first. I've tried so many things but I can't get a working Map to display, instead I get a blank outline of where a map should go and then some zoom buttons and a Google Logo. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

For the record:

- I'm testing on Stock Galaxy S3 i9300 - 4.3
- Included Google Play Services Library
- Included android.support.v4.jar
- Tried two different API keys
- Tried multiple 'Project Build Targets' (both Android and Google ones_

I am however using the API key generated from degug.keystore. Would that cause a problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Manifest:

`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<permission 
    android:name="com.example.geofence1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.geofence1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        />

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyB81f5fwV0MPK9ZA6Y-ESt2Rq_0T76xF7I"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.geofence1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>`
```

Main_Activity.java:

```
package com.example.geofence1;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
       }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try regenrating the key and extend activity

Comment: Everytime I encounter this problem I have 1) generated a new key in the Google API Console and 2) done a full uninstall of the app after changing the key in my manifest. Also if possible, do the test on a real device. It is fine to generate the key using the debug.keystore but you will of course have to use another key if you plan to make a releasable version.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm testing on device already and I've tried 3 different API keys. @Raghunandan - Tried Extending 'Activity' but it breaks everything that references 'Fragment' . I read somewhere it neeed to be 'Fragment?'